# A term for only a pre-noun and a post-noun adjective

Tags: adjectives, terminology

> The **red** ball is expensive.
>
> The ball is **red**.
>
> The answer is **absolutistic** in its nature.
>
> The **absolutistic** answer that he provided didn't quite fit the
> given problem.

In the four examples above I can easily place adjectives "red" and "absolutistic" before the noun that they are modifying or right after the verb "is".

However, I can't do that with all adjectives:

> The new law is **in force** as of today.
>
> The **in force** law gives more freedom to people.
>
> The Constitution is **in effect** now.
>
> The **in effect** Constitution must be observed.

My question is: Is it just because these are two-word adjectives or there exist some one-word adjectives that don't boast the same freedom of placement as "red" and "absolutistic"?

Additional question: Is there any grammar term for such adjectives that don't have such freedom?

The [Wikipedia page on adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective) provides such terms as Prepositive adjectives and Postpositive adjectives, but doesn't seem to provide a term for adjectives that can be both.

Comment: Wikipedia gives examples of the same adjective (happy) used in both ways. It doesn't imply that these terms describe _different_ adjectives.

Comment: @KateBunting - Neither did I. But I need a term for such an adjective like "happy", that is, an adjective that can be used in both ways -- can be both prepositive and postpositive. And a term for those adjectives that can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is interesting recent work on a very similar phenomenon by Adele Goldberg. This work is in linguistics, but it is written in quite a simple style, and can be understood by the non-specialist. Goldberg was interested in why you can say things like

- The boy is awake

but not

- The awake boy went home

See https://adele.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/277/2015/04/GoldbergBoyd2015_ReplyToYang-1.pdf

---

Traditionally (and often still today), *the red ball* is said to contain an **attributive** use of *red*, whereas *the ball is red* is said to contain a **predicative** use.

Comment: Thanks a million! Very interesting source and directly related to my question!

Comment: Glad to hear it. I just realised the linked paper is a reply to a criticism of Goldberg's original paper. You may want to look up the original paper first.

Comment: (The criticism is also worth reading if you're interested; Charles Yang is a very good linguist.)